# Speech Recognition Android NPE

Tags: java, android, eclipse, nullpointerexception, speech-recognition

I have a problem in my android app. The problem is Speech Recogntion is not working when it reaches the method startActivityForResult (intent, int) it shows that I have to add Bundle. The Speech recognition is added in a class that is called inside Adaper class not in MainActivity as people doing.

**Here is the code for Speech Recognition**

```
public class SpeechRecog extends Activity {

    private static final int VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE = 1001;
    ArrayList<String> thingsYouSaid = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void Start(Intent i, Context c) {
        i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "en-US");
        i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 1);
        i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Are You Done ,  yet? ");
        //try{
        startActivityForResult(i, VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE);
        //}catch(Exception e){
        //Toast.makeText(c, "SpeechRecogntion is not avalible on your device ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        //}

    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if ((requestCode == 
                VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE) && (resultCode == RESULT_OK)) {

            thingsYouSaid = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            if (checkResult())
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                        "You are done ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                        "You are not done ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }


    public boolean checkResult() {

        for (int i = 0; i < thingsYouSaid.size(); i++) {

            if ((thingsYouSaid.get(i).equals("done")) 
                    || (thingsYouSaid.get(i).equals("yes")))
                return true;

        }
        //if (textResult.equals("done")||(textResult.equals("yes")))
        //return true ; 

        return false;
    }

}
```

**Here the OnclickListenre inside adapter class**

```
Lh.btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        String[] items = db.GetItemArray(Lh.text);
        String[] itemFlags = db.GetItemsFlagsArray(Lh.text);
        //final itemHolder ihc = new itemHolder();

        if (Lh.btn.getText().equals("read")) {
            Lh.btn.setText("Pause");
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

                if (Integer.valueOf(itemFlags[i]) == 1) {

                    continue;
                }

                int timeofitem = Integer.parseInt(db.getItemTime(items[i]));
                //Toast.makeText(context, items[i] , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                TTS.Talk(items[i], 1);
                TTS.Scilence(timeofitem);

                SpeechRecog SP = new SpeechRecog();
                SP.Start(new Intent(), context);

                // checking  items
                ItemsFields itemToBeChanged = new ItemsFields(Lh.text, items[i], 0, timeofitem);
                itemToBeChanged.setFlag(1);
                db.updateItems(itemToBeChanged);

                //ihc.checkbox.setChecked(true); 
            }

            TTS.Talk("Congrats ,Your Checklist is Completed ", 1);


        } else {
            Lh.btn.setText("read");
            TTS.Talk("The Checklist is paused , Press again if you want to continue , Bye", 0);
            return;

        }
    }

});
```

**Here is what Debug says**

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception NullPointerException))  
        <VM does not provide monitor information>   
        SpeechRecog(Activity).startActivityForResult(Intent, int, Bundle) line: 3464    
        SpeechRecog(Activity).startActivityForResult(Intent, int) line: 3425    
        SpeechRecog.Start(Intent, Context) line: 24 
        ViewAdapter$1.onClick(View) line: 140   
        Button(View).performClick() line: 4475  
        View$PerformClick.run() line: 18786 
        Handler.handleCallback(Message) line: 730   
        ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 92 
        Looper.loop() line: 176 
        ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 5419    
        Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
        Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 525  
        ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 1046 
        ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 862 
        NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

**It shows this weird code after debging with highlight on**  * `<var>flagsMask</var>`

```
/**
 * Like {@link #startActivityForResult(Intent, int)}, but allowing you
 * to use a IntentSender to describe the activity to be started.  If
 * the IntentSender is for an activity, that activity will be started
 * as if you had called the regular {@link #startActivityForResult(Intent, int)}
 * here; otherwise, its associated action will be executed (such as
 * sending a broadcast) as if you had called
 * {@link IntentSender#sendIntent IntentSender.sendIntent} on it.
 *
 * @param intent       The IntentSender to launch.
 * @param requestCode  If >= 0, this code will be returned in
 *                     onActivityResult() when the activity exits.
 * @param fillInIntent If non-null, this will be provided as the
 *                     intent parameter to {@link IntentSender#sendIntent}.
 * @param flagsMask    Intent flags in the original IntentSender that you
 *                     would like to change.
 * @param flagsValues  Desired values for any bits set in
 *                     <var>flagsMask</var>
 * @param extraFlags   Always set to 0.
 * @param options      Additional options for how the Activity should be started.
 *                     See {@link android.content.Context#startActivity(Intent, Bundle)
 *                     Context.startActivity(Intent, Bundle)} for more details.  If options
 *                     have also been supplied by the IntentSender, options given here will
 *                     override any that conflict with those given by the IntentSender.
 */
public void startIntentSenderForResult(IntentSender intent, int requestCode,
                                       Intent fillInIntent, int flagsMask, int flagsValues, int extraFlags,
                                       Bundle options) throws IntentSender.SendIntentException {
    if (mParent == null) {
        startIntentSenderForResultInner(intent, requestCode, fillInIntent,
                flagsMask, flagsValues, this, options);
    } else if (options != null) {
        mParent.startIntentSenderFromChild(this, intent, requestCode,
                fillInIntent, flagsMask, flagsValues, extraFlags, options);
    } else {
        // Note we want to go through this call for compatibility with
        // existing applications that may have overridden the method.
        mParent.startIntentSenderFromChild(this, intent, requestCode,
                fillInIntent, flagsMask, flagsValues, extraFlags);
    }
}
```

Here is what log cat says

```
05-04 23:44:00.845: D/libEGL(24183): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
05-04 23:44:00.850: D/libEGL(24183): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
05-04 23:44:00.855: D/libEGL(24183): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
05-04 23:44:00.865: E/(24183): Device driver API match
05-04 23:44:00.865: E/(24183): Device driver API version: 23
05-04 23:44:00.865: E/(24183): User space API version: 23 
05-04 23:44:00.865: E/(24183): mali: REVISION=Linux-r3p2-01rel3 BUILD_DATE=Wed Oct  9 21:05:57 KST 2013 
05-04 23:44:00.970: D/OpenGLRenderer(24183): Enabling debug mode 0
05-04 23:44:01.020: D/AbsListView(24183): unregisterIRListener() is called 
05-04 23:44:01.045: D/AbsListView(24183): unregisterIRListener() is called 
05-04 23:44:01.080: D/AbsListView(24183): unregisterIRListener() is called 
05-04 23:44:01.170: D/AbsListView(24183): unregisterIRListener() is called 
05-04 23:44:02.630: D/AbsListView(24183): Get MotionRecognitionManager
05-04 23:44:02.785: W/ResourceType(24183): Invalid package identifier when getting bag for resource number 0xffffffff
05-04 23:44:02.795: W/ResourceType(24183): Invalid package identifier when getting bag for resource number 0xffffffff
05-04 23:44:02.805: W/ResourceType(24183): Invalid package identifier when getting bag for resource number 0xffffffff
05-04 23:44:02.810: W/ResourceType(24183): Invalid package identifier when getting bag for resource number 0xffffffff
```

Comment: Are you able to show us both versions of the `startActivityForResult` method, and indicate which ones are lines 3425 and 3464?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but startActivityForResult is already defined so I only have to call it. When adding a bundle it says that I have to add a tag for Jelly Bean or Newapi.

Answer (score 2):

Never instantiate activities with `new`.

Use an `Intent` to launch new activities or use an existing activity instantiated by the framework for `onActivityResult()`.

For the latter, replace

```
SpeechRecog SP = new SpeechRecog();
SP.Start(new Intent(), context);
```

with the code from `Start()` (i.e. setting up an `Intent` and calling `startActivityForResult()` and pull `onActivityResult()` to that activity.

Comment: you mean I just do like this>> SpeechRecog SP; 
                        SP.Start(new Intent()  , context);

Comment: can you explain your solution more 'cause I'm not that expert in android development :) thanx

Comment: Thank you, but I didn't understand yet, you mean that I pass new Intent for startActivityForResult() not the same one ?! What do mean by pull to onActivityResult ()?!  Sorry for not understanding :)